# Display real live progress in perl

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I have this code in cgi.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "content-type: text/html \n\n";
print "<html><head><style>div.section{  font-size: 12px;    border: 1px solid #999999;  background-color: #EFEFEF;  margin: 10px 15px;}p{   font-family: \"Arial\", \"Helvetica\", \"sans-serif\";  font-size: 14px;    color: #444444; line-height: 30px;  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;  padding: 0 0 6px 0; text-align: center;}</style></head><body><div class=\"section\"><p>";
print "<b>YAMJ successfully updated your movie collection</b>";
print "</p><b>YAMJ output:</b><br>";
print "<pre>";
my $status = system("/usr/local/YAMJ/run.sh");
print "</pre>";
print "</div></body></html>";
```

The code was created by MissileHugger for YAMJ in Synology. The thing is each time user open the app on synology, it just gives you blank page while the script do its thing.

I was wondering, is there a way to output real time data progress of what the script is doing at that time? Similar to when we install windows software, there is status showing what file being copied etc.

Anyone has any idea if I can do this?

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: We need lots more info to help you here. Does YAMJ run as a CGI script? What do you expect that the above code does, for example the `$status` variable is never used and `system` only returns the exit code of the command executed.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be easily done. Reason: HTTP is stateless, and a browser may render the page only once it is fully loaded.

```
   SERVER     COMMUNICATION  CLIENT
+------------+              +---------+
| Rendezvous | <----------- | Client  |
+------------+  get status  | Browser |
    ^              via      |         |
    | write     javascript  |         |
    | status                |         |
+------------+    invoke    |         |
|   Process  | <----------- |         |
+------------+              +---------+
```

Here is an algorithm you can use:

1. The client browser requests a CGI script. This kicks off a long running process. It returns an unique session ID to the browser
2. The long running process continuously rewrites a rendezvous file with its status.
3. The client browser polls the rendezvous file specified by the ID and updates the web page using javascript. HTML5 has a [`<progress>` meter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/progress) element you may be able to use.
4. After the session is finished, the file is deleted from the server filesystem.

In the simplest case, you point the browser to a page that is rewritten continuously, and the browser is instructed to reload that page every few seconds. In the era of AJAX, this is largely obsolete. Loading the contents via javascript will be smoother and allows the transmission of complex state via JSON, e.g.:

```
{ "status": 0.4,
  "comments": ["loaded a file",
               "doing really hard math",
               "almost finished - just a moment please"]}
```

instead of a plain-text

```
Status: 40%
```

Having the server push these events to the browser would be really elegant, however, I have no idea how that could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome code.  Thank you so much for your solution.  I've been working on this for the last 3 days..

This is what I did to update your script to work for my program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

$|++; #This is needed to disable buffering

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
# This header is a quick hack which denies browser to gzip/deflate your output
print "Content-Encoding: plain\r\n\r\n";

&load_buffer; #This keeps the browser window printing progress as it's running
```

## From this point on any print statement will work as the program is running.

## example Test

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 11; ++$i)

{
print "$i<br>\n";

sleep(1);

}
```

Subroutine

```
sub load_buffer {

my $cmd = qq{perl -e "\$|++; print ' ' and sleep(1) for 1..1"};
open my $PROC, '-|', $cmd or die $!;
while (sysread $PROC, $buffer, 1) { print "<!-- Browser shoudln't      cache this chunk ", ' ' x 1000, "-->\n";} 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable autoflush of `STDOUT` filehandle to achieve this.
Basically, putting the following code on the top of your script (after the shebang) should help:

```
$|++;
```

Please reffer to [previous answers on autoflush question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804220/perl-operator-dollar-sign-pipe-plus-plus) for more details on autoflush.

The following oneliners can show you the difference:

```
perl -e "$|++; print '#' and sleep(1) for 1..10"
perl -e "print '#' and sleep(1) for 1..10"
```

P.S.: I suppose you can see ASCII progress bar if you run /usr/local/YAMJ/run.sh in the terminal.

UPD:

And this supposed to work, but:

1. Apache might gzip your output and send as a single chunk, if compression enabled
2. Browser (Chrome for example) buffer output too.

Therefore you have to perform some additional work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$|++;

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
# This header is a quick hack which denies browser to gzip/deflate your output
print "Content-Encoding: plain\r\n\r\n";

print "<html><body><h1>Start</h1>\n";

my $cmd = qq{perl -e "\$|++; print '#' and sleep(1) for 1..100"};

# Start your command, read it's output byte by byte
# and send it to the browser with a 1000+ bytes long comment
# which should prevent browser from caching just a single character
open my $PROC, '-|', $cmd or die $!;

my $buffer;
while (sysread $PROC, $buffer, 1) {
    print $buffer;
    print "<!-- Browser shoudln't cache this chunk ", ' ' x 1000, "-->\n";
}

print "<h1>Done</h1></body></html>";
```

Comment: Given that this is a Web page or HTML document, this isn't going to help.