# tail -f file1 | perl -pe '$_' > file2 does not output anything to file2

Tags: bash, perl, buffer

This command does not output anything to file2:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo content > file1
tail -f file1 | perl -pe '$_' > file2
```

Whereas these commands work ok:

```
tail -f file1 > file2
tail -f file1 | perl -pe '$_'
tail file1 | perl -pe '$_' > file2
tail -f /tmp/file1 | while read line; do echo $line | perl -pe '$_' > /tmp/file2 ; done
```

Anyone knows what's happening?

Answer (score 5):

`perl` has detected that stdout is not a terminal. For efficiency, it waits until it has a full block of data to write. Since you don't provide more data, it won't write anything until `tail` exits and the program can finish.

You can [enable autoflushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804220/perl-operator-dollar-sign-pipe-plus-plus) with `$|++`:

```
tail -f file1 | perl -pe '$|++; $_' > file2
```

Answer (score 2):

The one with no output suffers from a combination of buffered output and non-termination. `tail -f` will never exit, waiting forever for `file1` to grow. However, the output of `perl` is (apparently) buffered, so it waits until it has some minimal amount of output (more than a single line containing "content") to actually write to `file2`. Until more output is generated, or `perl` exits, the output remains unflushed.

Each of your working examples either terminates, flushing any buffered output at that time; or its output is unbuffered, allowing it to appear as it is generated.