# Best way to alternate a variable value in loop? (Perl)

Tags: perl, loops

```
my @arr = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

my $counter = 0;
foreach my $a (@arr) {
    my $str;
    if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
        $str = 'hi';
    } else {
        $str = 'bye';
    }
    print $str . "\n";
    $counter++;
}
```

What is the best way to alternate between two different values for each iteration of a while loop? Simple example above, is there a better way than keeping a counter and modding to find even values?

Comment: There are probably dozens of different ways to do what you've described. Define "better"/"best." Fewest lines of code? Most readable? Fastest?

Comment: Perhaps `$toggle = ! $toggle;` (where you currently increment the counter), but it's not really less code or easier to understand.

Comment: I guess "Best" could be fewest lines of code. I would prefer to not have to use a counter, but I didn't know if Perl had a special way that this could be accomplished.

Comment: Worst way to do it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959230

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my @arr = qw( a b c );

for my $i (0..$#arr) {
    print "$arr[$i] ", $i % 2 ? 'bye' : 'hi', "\n";
}
```

Comment: You could also use binary operator: `$i & 1`

Answer (score 1):

Good name.

```
my /*boolean*/ $even = 0;
foreach ...

    next if ... # skipping line

    $even = !$even;

    ... # work
    print $even ? 'hi' : 'bye';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do like this:

```
...
my @arr = (1..9);

for (my $i=0; $i<scalar(@arr); $i++) {
  my $str = ($i % 2 == 0) ? 'hi' : 'bye';
  print "$str\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my ($foo, $bar) = qw(foo bar);
for (0..10) {
  print "$foo\n";
  ($foo, $bar) = ($bar, $foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A weird one, but no counters and no *modding to find even values*:

```
use strict;

sub foo {
    shift || return and bar(@_);
    print "doing something with Value2 \n";
}

sub bar {
    shift || return and foo(@_);
    print "doing something with Value1 \n";
}


foo(1..100);
```

Do whatever you want by calling `foo()` or `bar()` and chosing an even or odd values insted of 100. Maybe you would like to use `$#arr` insted of hardcoded values and so on.

But please don't write code like this.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't resist:

```
my @arr = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
my @alt = qw( hi bye );

my $counter = 0;
foreach my $a (@arr) {
    print $alt[($counter++ % 2)] . "\n";
}
```

Or per dolmen's comment using "&" which should be more efficient compared to modulo (%)

```
my @arr = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
my @alt = qw( hi bye );

my $counter = 0;
foreach my $a (@arr) {
    print $alt[($counter++ & 1)] . "\n";
}
```