# sleep function stops script

Tags: perl, sleep

I am trying to create an automation script. I ran into an issue were the sleep() command is preventing my script from running. Any ideas on what is happening? I'm currently trying out some 3rd party sleep libraries, i'm just curious for why this would happen?

Example script below:

```
while("1")
{
    sleep 2;
    print "test";
}
```

This script never prints out "test", but if i remove the sleep function then it works perfectly fine other then it doesn't sleep when i want it too.

Comment: Also [Why won't my perl daemon print?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32676834/176646)

Comment: Good catch @ThisSuitIsBlackNot.

Comment: Also I just realized your name is not _ThisSuiteIsNotBlack_. How long have I been reading this wrong? oO

Comment: lol, it happens @simbabeque ;)

Comment: thanks guys!!!! seems to have solved me issue!!!